# How can I see the magnitude and frequency of a signal (DFT) in PLECS?

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink

I am trying to obtain the Fourier transform of a signal by using the DFT of PLECS but I got some weird results.

Here is a very simple sinewave generator and the DFT block:

DFT_plecs_1

[image]

Here are the results on the scope:

DFT_plecs_2

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do `Ts`, `samples` and `n:` in the DFT block mean ? If the sampling period is `Ts : 8` **seconds**, will it be able to *correctly* represent a `1 Hz` signal ? Please add a picture of the time domain scope (apart from the DFT scope which is already included in the question). Also note that the frequency resolution decreases with decrease in the the number of samples used for DFT. You may want to choose a higher value for `samples` (depending on your actual needs).

Comment: Ts is sampling frequency, n is the order of harmonics which means from 0 to N-1, Samples is N. I used number of samples 8 just to make it easy to found out how to use the DFT block of plecs

Comment: `Ts` is sampling frequency and not sampling time ? Are you sure about it ? I am not familiar with the DFT taking an input called *order of harmonics*. According to the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition), it takes only the samples (`x(n)`) and number of samples (`N`) as input. The `Ts` or `Fs` can be used to convert the frequency variable (`k`) into physical units (say, Hz). But what is the purpose of `n: [0 2 3 4 5]`. Why did you assign that variable as `[0 2 3 4 5]` ? (And why is `1` missing ?) Please add a picture of the sine signal also.

Comment: **(1)** [This document](http://read.pudn.com/downloads592/ebook/2422992/plecsmanual3.1.8.pdf#page=415) tells me that sampling time (and not sampling frequency) is the parameter. **I would say that the value `TS: 8` is wrong**. **(2)** If you are starting out, i suggest that you set `n : [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]` so that the full spectrum is visible. Also plotting the result (all 8 harmonics) against time will make the result difficult to interpret. **(3)** Also, try simulating for a longer duration.

Comment: I am sorry, Yes, Ts is sampling time and I changed it to 1/8. I simulated for 200s and the result did not change greatly

Comment: Did you change `n: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]` ?

Comment: yes I did and it shows the same.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental frenquency of DFT block should always equal to 1 Hz which is the fundamental frequency of your signal. That means, if Ts is 1/8s, then the number of samples should be 8, if you increase Ts to 1/2s, then the number should be 2.